# Understanding a trigonometric step

Tags: trigonometry

In my textbook it says that to obatin the followin equation:
$$
c_1 = \frac{F_0}{\sqrt{(k-m\Omega^2)^2+(\Omega r)^2}}
$$

you have to put:
$$
\tan \phi = - \frac{ \Omega r }{k-m \Omega^2} 
$$

into:
$$
(-m\Omega^2 \cos \phi - r \Omega \sin \phi +k \cos \phi)c_1 = F_0
$$

yet I don't get it

Comment: Devide $\cos\phi$ on both sides of your last equation, and use the fact that $$\frac{1}{\cos^2\phi}=\sec^2\phi=1+\tan^2\phi.$$

Answer (score 0):

If $\tan \phi = - \frac{ \Omega r }{k-m \Omega^2}$

then  $\\
\sin\phi = -\frac {\Omega r}{\sqrt{(k-m \Omega^2)^2 + (\Omega r)^2}}\\
\cos\phi = \frac {(k-m \Omega^2)}{\sqrt{(k-m \Omega^2)^2 + (\Omega r)^2}}\\
$

Comment: But if i put them into the first equation I still can't solve it : $$ \frac {(k-m \Omega^2)}{\sqrt{(k-m \Omega^2)^2 + (\Omega r)^2}}(-m\Omega^2)+r\Omega \frac {r\Omega}{\sqrt{(k-m \Omega^2)^2 + (\Omega r)^2}}+k\frac {(k-m \Omega^2)}{\sqrt{(k-m \Omega^2)^2+ (\Omega r)^2}}=\frac{F_0}{c1}
$$
$$\frac {m^2\Omega^2+r^2\Omega^2+k^2}{\sqrt{(k-m \Omega^2)^2 + (\Omega r)^2}}=\frac{F_0}{c1}$$ Am i doing a stupid mistake?

Comment: $\frac {(k-m \Omega^2)}{\sqrt{(k-m \Omega^2)^2 + (\Omega r)^2}}(-m\Omega^2)+r\Omega \frac {r\Omega}{\sqrt{(k-m \Omega^2)^2 + (\Omega r)^2}}+k\frac {(k-m \Omega^2)}{\sqrt{(k-m \Omega^2)^2+ (\Omega r)^2}}=\frac {(k-m \Omega^2)^2+ (\Omega r)^2}{\sqrt{(k-m \Omega^2)^2+ (\Omega r)^2}}=\sqrt{(k-m \Omega^2)^2+ (\Omega r)^2}$